# Heatmap for Link clicks with only one function for all

Tags: javascript, html

I got a problem while writung a code for a Heatmap based on link clicks.

I have a Page with different articel teasers. When i click the link the artical itself opensup. Now i want to track in real time how often which articel is clicked so i can decide which articel is relevant to users and place it like on the first articel space and so on.

Therefor i wrote a function which tracks the clicks with a counter and show them in the div.
Now my problem is. That i cant write like 20 functions for counters and 20 for resets. I want to have one function which can decide which articel was clicked and add +1 to the counter of the link.

My Code for the counter and the reset + the link text gets red after more than 5 clicks.

```
var count1 = 0;

function heatmap(id) {  
    if(id==1){
        count1++;
        document.getElementById("count1").innerHTML = count1;
    }

    if(count1>=5){
        document.getElementById("link1").style.color = "red";
    }
}

function reset(id){
    if(id==1){
        count1=0;
        document.getElementById("count1").innerHTML = 0;
    }
}
```

My html code so far

```
<div style="text-align:center; font-size:20px; font-family: arial;">
    <div id="link1" onclick="heatmap(1)">This is the first Link</div><br>
    <div id="count1">0</div><br>
    <button onclick="reset(1)">RESET</button>
    <button onclick="save(1)">SAVE</button>
</div>
```

Now my main problem is that i only want one function for all the link tracking.

Is there a possibiblity to write the code in a way the variables are dynamicly so that the function can decide which link was clicked.

for example something like:

```
var count + ID = 0;

function heatmap(ID) {  
        count + ID ++;
        document.getElementById("count" + ID).innerHTML = count+ID;
    }

    if(count + ID >=5){
        document.getElementById("link + ID").style.color = "red";
    }
}

function reset(id){
        count + ID =0;
        document.getElementById("count + ID").innerHTML = 0;
    }
}
```

I already searched this homepage and did some google searches but all i found was working with arrays or lists. But i think this wouldnt realy work for me since i want to give my function an ID and later add this id to the varibale name like `count + ID = count | count + ID = count2` same with the `document.getElementById("count" + ID).innerHTML = count+ID; = document.getElementById("count1").innerHTML = count1;`

As you can see the link got a `onclick="heatmap(ID)"` this ID will be added to every articel Link and will go from the first articel with 1 to the last articel with like 20.

If i change an Articel the counter will be resetet and the ID will be changed to its position. So there will always be a identifier with the ID which can be used for the counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop through all articles and store a counter on each element which you update or reset once the specific button inside the article was clicked:

```
var articles = document.querySelectorAll('article');

for(var i=0; i < articles.length; i++) {
    articles[i].querySelector('.save').addEventListener('click', updateCounter);
    articles[i].querySelector('.reset').addEventListener('click', resetCounter);
    articles[i]['counter'] = 0;
}

function updateCounter(ev) {
    var article = ev.target.parentNode;

    article.counter++;
    article.querySelector('.counter').innerHTML = article.counter;

    /* Some server synchronisation should go here */
}

function resetCounter(ev) {
    var article = ev.target.parentNode;

    article.counter = 0;
    article.querySelector('.counter').innerHTML = article.counter;

    /* Some server synchronisation should go here */
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L78A4/3/)

But to permanently store the counters you have to synchronize your results with a server, respectively a database.

If you just want to use one function you could realize it like this:

```
var articles = document.querySelectorAll('article');

for(var i=0; i < articles.length; i++) {
    articles[i].querySelector('.save').addEventListener('click', checkCounter);
    articles[i].querySelector('.reset').addEventListener('click', checkCounter);
    articles[i]['counter'] = 0;
}

function checkCounter(ev) {
    var article = ev.target.parentNode,
        button = ev.target;

    if(button.classList[0] === 'save') {
        article.counter++;
    } else if(button.classList[0] === 'reset') {
        article.counter = 0;
    }

    article.querySelector('.counter').innerHTML = article.counter;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L78A4/4/)

Comment: Thank you for your help and for the fiddle Demos. this realy help me out a lot. thank you